# How to extract thumbnails from facebook video url

Tags: facebook, url, video, thumbnails

Is there anyway to get thumbnails from facebook video urls?. Anyone with useful information should help me please. I've tried previous posts on this but none seemed to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: No. But you can use the API to ask for thumbnail

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take it by facebook graph API like this http request:

http://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/?fields=picture&access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS_TOKEN>

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but when I did I got the following error "{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "ACC2fu5Dew4l5MbCl-Sd-Vk"
   }
}"